# Refining a simple delete-item one-liner

Tags: windows-10, bash, powershell, cmd.exe, shell-script

so I was wanting to upgrade my delete-item one-liner. I want to breakup the main filepath(\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar\ProcessorHandlers\Test) into 2 variables that are defined at the top of the script. Something like:

1. $rootdir = "\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar"
2. $svcdir = {insert service name here} (i.e., Message Router, Processor Handlers)

And then create a 3rd variable that is the full directory path, which just glues 1 + 2 together, which I know can just be done with the "+" operator, please correct me if I'm wrong.

The idea is that, eventually, I'll be able to run a foreach loop to grab and set the svcdir path, dynamically glue together the full directory path of where you're wanting to delete files, run the delete process, and then move onto the next service's folder. I hope I explained that correct. If by chance anyway would like to see the one-line I've been using, I'll put it here down below:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse \\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar\ProcessorHandlers\Test\*.* | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the Path and LiteralPath Property of `Remove-Item` accept wildcards, so your current one liner would already work without `Get-ChildItem`

`Remove-Item \\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar\ProcessorHandlers\Test\*.* -Recurse -Force`

About the "glueing together" I would suggest either `Join-Path` or the Format operator `-f`.

`Join-Path` example (with this you don't have to worry about backslashes):

```
PS C:\> $rootdir = "\\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar"
PS C:\> $svcdir = "Message Router"
PS C:\> Join-Path $rootdir $svcdir
\\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar\Message Router
```

`-f` example (note the `{0}` thats where the argument you supply will be placed):

```
PS C:\> $rootdir = "\\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar\{0}"
PS C:\> $svcdir = "Message Router"
PS C:\> $rootdir -f $svcdir
\\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar\Message Router
```

So yes you can foreach over all paths and do this glueing stuff, however you can also just supply all paths you want directly to `Remove-Item` since it can handle an array:

```
cd "\\HQDEVAPP004\C$\LoneStar"
Remove-Item ".\Message Router\*.*",".\SomeOtherPath" -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir! This post was very informative. I'm still pretty new to PS and not only did you answer my question, you also gave me knowledge on other functions and operators that could help me in future scripting. Thank you!